# windows 7 - sql server 2012 - Maintenanace Cleanup Task

Tags: sql-server, backup, maintenance, ssms

My Team Foundation Server creates backups. I want to **clear backups** that are older than 5 days.  Create Maintenanace Cleanup Task in Maintenance Plans of Management of **Sql Server 2012**. Point there folder, file extension `bak`, checkbox 'Delete files based on the age of the file at task run time' is checked. Saved task.

When I execute it, got error: `Execution failed. See the maintenance plan and SQL Server Agent job history logs for details.`

In Sql Server **Agent** job history:
Message

> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
>   Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit  Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  7:31:58 
>   Progress: 2013-02-05 07:31:58.66     Source:
>   {7F5A7CED-005D-4A73-B4D0-B09CF3B45934}      Executing query "DECLARE
>   @Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER      EXECUTE msdb..sp...".: 100% complete  End
>   Progress  Error: 2013-02-05 07:31:58.71     Code: 0xC002F210
>   Source: Maintenance Cleanup Task Execute SQL Task     Description:
>   Executing the query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_delete_file
>   0,N'C:\Users\ypa..." failed with the following error:
>   "xp_delete_file() returned error 2, '**Can not find the file specified**'". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
>   "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly,
>   or connection not established correctly.  End Error  Warning:
>   2013-02-05 07:31:58.71     Code: 0x80019002     Source: Subplan_2
>   Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The
>   Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1)
>   reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs
>   when the number of errors reaches the number specified in
>   MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors. 
>   End Warning  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
>   Started:  7:31:58  Finished: 7:31:58  Elapsed:  0.687 seconds.  The
>   package execution failed.  The step failed.

`Can not find the file specified`? Rechecked backup path. It's valid.

According to @Md advice

1. set my current windows **user** to sql server agent(MSSQLSERVER) process and type **password** there. **Restarted** this **service**.
2. check properties of backup folder: on security tab  I see that my windows user has **Full control** on this folder

The **same error**.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not running the SQL Server Agent as a user that has permission to that directory. Check `services.msc` and see what user the agent is running as. Then, either change it to a user that can modify the directory in question, or add the current user to the ACL on the folder where your backups are.

Comment: done. but fail. Details above.